# how to make deleting grease pencil strokes in a different frame create a new keyframe like moving strokes do

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

when auto keying is on, modifying the strokes in a differente frame will create a new keyframe, except when i delete a stroke, in which it will act as if im just modidying the original. This is really annoying since the first thing i do in a lot of cases is deleting the part i want to animate from a drawing.

Comment: I'm on 3.6 and erasing part of a stroke does create a new frame

Comment: Oh yeah, i meant deleting, like using x to delete strokes, not switching to eraser.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the first image, move the timeline to the next frame, press I (choose if to duplicate a single layer or all layers).

Here you can edit as needed.